# JDeveloper deployment "Page can't be displayed" error

Tags: weblogic, jdeveloper

For development, I'm using the integrated weblogic feature in JDeveloper. So far, this has worked fine. I was recently put onto a different project, however, and when I try to deploy it, I'm having trouble. Here are the steps I take:

1. Run->Debug Server Instance (IntegratedWeblogicServer)
2. In the Projects, I right-click on Web Content->index.html and select Debug.

According to the log, the applicatoin deploys successfully with the target URL of http://localhost:7101/Myapp-Myapp-context-root/index.html and it then attempts to open the page.

However, this gets me a "This page can't be displayed" in Internet Explorer. No error messages in JDeveloper's log or IE's console. I realize this doesn't give a lot of information to work with, but it's all I've got right now.

One other thing, and I don't know how relevant this is, but if I attempt to refresh the page or enter it into a different browser, it redirects to https://localhost:7102/Myapp-Myapp-context-root/index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. It switching to a secure port was related, as the finalized product is supposed to do that. Development requires the security-constraint fields in the web.xml to be commented out.